# Content script loads automatically

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I am developing a chrome extension right now. It serves its purpose but the problem is that the content script gets executed on its own whenever I open a new tab and visit a site. The problem is that there is an alert in the content script & it starts to become annoying when the alert gets triggered on visiting every new site.

Currently I am triggering the content script from my background script by using the chrome.tabs.executeScript API. However, I have noticed that whenever I open a new tab & visit a new site, the code in content script gets executed automatically even if the criteria for it getting triggered hasn't been met in the background script.

Is this the normal behavior? Is this how all chrome extensions are supposed to work? If yes, is there a way to prevent this? For now, I have declared my content script as a background script, but I would still like to find a fix for this.

Here is my manifest - manifest.json:

```
"content_scripts" : [
{
    "matches" : [ "<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["raisealert.js"]
}
],


"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
},
```

Here is the background script - background.js:

```
if(condition met)
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
    code: 'var config = ' + JSON.stringify(config)
    }, function() {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: 'raisealert.js'}, function() {
            console.log("Alarm triggered");
        });
    });
```

And here is the content script - raisealert.js

```
alert("sample alert raised");
```

Comment: Don't declare it in manifest. As you can see in the documentation, it loads the script automatically.

Comment: Ahhhh....Thank you so much. Dunno why I missed that part of the documentation. I thought it was mandatory to declare every script in the extension in the manifest. If you put your comment as an answer, I will accept it. Thanks @wOxxOm

Answer (score 1):

You can have a content_script load automatically and with no programming effort on your part by calling it up in the content_scripts section of the manifest.

You can do this for all URLs or you can define fairly fine-grained url patterns that the script should load on. See [Manifest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#registration) injection

If you want to inject the script conditionally on criteria other than just the URL then you can use [programmatic injection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi) - this could be based on criteria such as the content of the page or whether someone clicks the browser action button or selects a right click context menu option you've defined.

Programmatic injection will often use the chrome.tabs.onupdated listener to check for particular urls or content and then inject or not.

If your extension is something that potentially anyone *might* want to use on any page then it's usually best to inject it based on a deliberate action by the user, e.g. in your case, as you say, it is annoying (understatement) to get an alert on every tab and page that loads.

Even if your script has no visible annoyances, having it load in every page automatically is rarely a good idea unless it has near zero impact on the page.

If it's designed to work on a specific site then injecting via the manifest with an appropriate url pattern filter is often best.